# In house iOS builds from AppCenter asking to register device

Tags: ios, hockeyapp, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

In HockeyApp we always used an Apple Enterprise build (also called In House) to provide a test app to some clients so they could easy test new updates. Now with AppCenter we want to achieve the same, so we compile the build in AppCenter and choose the Enterprise scheme. The app is build correctly on AppCenter with the correct scheme and correctly distributed.

Now when I want to download the app with a new account and new device I reach the "Get started page". From there I have to add a new device (and iOS is asking me to install a new certificate). When that's finished, the AppCenter site states that my device was successfully added. But when I want to open the app, I keep going to the "Get started" page. Anyone else experiencing this issue? Or should we move back to HockeyApp where we never had any issues like this.

In the AppCenter build log, the identifier is correct, the scheme is correct, the aps-environment is set to production.

Comment: Some users are having this issue, some users don't, I also have this issue

Comment: It was working the following day, still a weird issue, since it was happening on multiple devices